# how to make indeterminate checkbox checked in ngx-treeview

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, ngx-treeview

I am using this library https://leovo2708.github.io/ngx-treeview/#/components.

However I have requirement that i need to show parent node as checked if any child is checked. So instead of indeterminate state, I need to show it as checked.. is it possible?

Comment: I supouse you can change the function onChildCheckedChange of the treeview-item.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use treeview Object with checked property if checkbox is checked then will return true either will show false